# How can I use Optionals instead of nested if statement?

Tags: java, option-type

```
public Message setMsg() {
    Message message = null;
    if (send != null || receive != null) {
        message = new Message();
        if (receive != null) {
            message.setReceive(receive);
        }
        if (send != null) {
            message.setSend(send);
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

How can I use Optionals in this case instead of this nested if statement?

Comment: Use `final Message` and `if` - `else if` - `else` to get clean and comprehensible code.

Comment: The most straightforward way here would be making a stream of 2 `receive` and `send`, map them to `Optionals` of their kind, and reduce them to an optional message.

Comment: Regard the previous comment as a don't :) Strive to make the listed snippet simpler, forget about rewriting it with Optional. Some points: the method name (does it return or set?), the return type (is set* supposed to return), the last return (always null), too many checks (do you need the first one?), do you need to check before setting (what is being stored in an empty message, `null`s? so why check?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you're trying to achieve but if send and receive were `Optional` objects you could do something like this:

```
public Message setMsg() {
    if (!send.isPresent() && !receive.isPresent()) {
        return null;
    }

    Message message = new Message();
    send.ifPresent(message::setSend);
    receive.ifPresent(message::setReceive);
    return message;
}
```

Comment: If they are not optional, they can be made optional using `Optional.ofNullable(send)`. Upvoted.

Comment: Tnx! This is very useful!